# How to access Cookie properties i.e name,version,values etc in ios using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cookies

I am using cookies for authentication in my ios app for that i need to access cookie name,version or value.I can get cookies but I faced error in accessing cookies stating "NSTPCookieName is not the property of cookie".

Answer (score 1):

The following code should help you get the names, values, and versions of the cookies.

```
for cookie in NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies! {
    print(cookie.name + " - " + cookie.value + "-" + cookie.version)
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: How to make the UIWebView class automatically store cookies for the pages that are loaded and reloaded after app launches?Do we need to work on App Delegate?I can't get cookies that are generated after webpage   loads

Answer (score 0):

```
            let dataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
            
            dataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
                for cookie in cookies {
                    print(cookie.name)
                    print(cookie.value)
                    print(cookie.version)
                    print("------------")
                }
            }
```